# How do I add more images to a background Jpanel?

Tags: java, swing

```
package Main;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Background {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Window Name
        JFrame F = new JFrame("Xiao's World");

        //Background Image
        try{
            F.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("src/Main/sky.jpg")))));

        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            //Case if image is not available
            System.out.println("Image doesn't exist.");
        }

        //Frame setup and rules
        F.setResizable(false);
        F.pack();
        F.setSize(800, 600);
        F.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

You see I can easily display a background no problem but I want a picture to be displayed on top of this background along with a few others is there a way to make a method to easily display multiply images on top of each other?

I'm trying to create a scene but it's kind of difficult because most tutorials are background imaging and not scene making. Also if you could help me so I can set up a stream of music to go alone with it that would be great, I have the images and the files I just need a code to help me set it up. I'm not that good with methods so explanations are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a custom component, using something like `JPanel`
- Override it's `paintComponent` method.
- Use a `List` to maintain the z-ordering of the images and paint them to the component using `Graphics#drawImage`

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

You will also want to take a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) to get a good understanding of how you can interact with the `Graphics` context.

While Swing is double buffered by default, it uses a passive rendering engine, this means that updates to the UI are done at it's discretion.

Eventually, you will want to take control of the rendering process so you can update the UI when you want it to be updated, to do this, you will need to look into `BufferingStrategy`.  You find out more by looking at [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html) and [`BufferStrategy` JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html)

Using...

[image: Sky][image: Mountains][image: Tree]

The following code can produce...

[image]

This just generates a random point where 0-1000 trees can be added to the scene...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage sky, mountains, tree;
        private List<Point> treePoints;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                sky = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Sky.png"));
                mountains = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Mountians.png"));
                tree = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Tree.png"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            treePoints = new ArrayList<>(25);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.anchor = gbc.SOUTH;

            JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 1000);
            slider.setValue(0);
            add(slider, gbc);
            slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    int count = slider.getValue();
                    if (count == 0) {
                        treePoints.clear();
                    } else if (count < treePoints.size()) {
                        treePoints = treePoints.subList(0, count - 1);
                    } else {

                        Rectangle skyBounds = getSkyBounds();
                        int y = (skyBounds.y + skyBounds.height) - tree.getHeight();
                        while (treePoints.size() < count) {

                            int x = skyBounds.x + (int)Math.round((Math.random() * (skyBounds.width + tree.getWidth()))) - tree.getWidth();
                            treePoints.add(new Point(x, y));

                        }

                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        protected Rectangle getSkyBounds() {

            int x = (getWidth() - sky.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - sky.getHeight()) / 2;

            return new Rectangle(x, y, sky.getWidth(), sky.getHeight());

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return sky == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(sky.getWidth(), sky.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            Rectangle skyBounds = getSkyBounds();

            g2d.drawImage(sky, skyBounds.x, skyBounds.y, this);
            g2d.drawImage(mountains, 
                            skyBounds.x, 
                            skyBounds.y + skyBounds.height - (mountains.getHeight()), 
                            this);

            for (Point p : treePoints) {
                g2d.drawImage(tree, p.x, p.y, this);
            }

            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: +1. Just to add a bit, since it looks like the OP is making a game of some sort I would recommend looking into using `Canvas` with a custom `render` method using `BufferingStrategy`. It just seem more suitable for the task.

Comment: I don't get these, either because I'm a noob or something else, but I don't want to use code to draw an image I just want to use code to implement my own pictures. Sorry if that's what these tutorials are doing, but again I don't understand what I'm trying to code by listening to them.

Comment: You want to show layered images on to the screen?  Or you want to merge a bunch of images and save them to another file?

Comment: @HillaAlduh Well the answer didn't say you shout write code to read a bitmap and map it on to a raster your self. Nevertheless you have to write some code to achieve your goal. Trust me on this, the suggested API is a far easier then most when it comes to rendering.

Comment: @DimaMaligin Given the OP's current level of experience and understanding, that might be pushing them just a little hard. Still a valid point

Comment: yes I want layered images, I'm sorry if I'm too low level but it's the only way for me to learn is to start simple. so if you could help me set up a layer of images that would be great, I just want to see if my scene will work together as one if I put them together.

Comment: @MadProgrammer In that case I suppose you suggested `JPanel` due to it's simplicity over `Canvas` with `BufferStrategy`, which is reasonable, although if OP wants absolute positioning with `JPanel`, `null` `Layout`'s can be a pain.

Comment: Right, then start with the linked tutorials, this will give you the grounding you will need to get started

Comment: @DimaMaligin The main reason I wouldn't jump to `BufferingStrategy` right now is that it introduces a whole bunch of complexity that the OP just doesn't need right now, yes, eventually they will need to investigate this, but I bet they have no idea of the difference between a passive and active rendering algorithm or `Thread`s...small steps :P

Comment: I was trying to make a sky and in the front a mountain and in the far front a tree line...that's all I was doing...not all this complicated mumbo jumbo.

Comment: That's because you don't understand what those tutorials are trying to tell or the means by which they can be used solve your problem.  Game programming isn't like desktop app programming, you need to get down and dirty with the `Graphics` layer and put it together yourself.

Comment: well at least tell me how I can use this because all this tells me is how it works it doesn't tell me what I need to type...

Comment: how do I set it up for my code because all I get is constant errors.